# center div within 100% width div

Tags: css, html, center

I am trying the Blueprint CSS framework, and am having a hard time figuring out how to do the overall layout.

It seems Blueprint (as far as I have understood it so far) makes you use a set page width at 950px. I guess you could change that with some modification, but in any case there has to be some width, so that's fine. The problem is, even if I want the main content of the page to be 950px wide, I want 100% wide headers and footers.

So I have placed a header and a footer outside the main "container" div that's 950px wide. I set the header div to 100%. And then I have a "headerContent" div inside it (containing menu, logo, etc), which has a 950px width (span-24 in Blueprint terms). But I want the headerContent div to be centered within the header div.

I have always used the "margin: 0 auto" trick to do this, but for some reason it doesn't work at all now.

Here's the html:

```
            <div id="header" class="blueheader">

                <div id="headerContent" class="span-24">

                    <div id="logo" class="span-6">

                        <a href="/">

                            <img src="/images/expertinfo.png" width="230" height="62" />

                            </a>

                    </div>

                    <div id="menucontainer" class="span-14"><ul id="menu"><li>

<a href='/Services/Index'>TJ&#196;NSTER</a></li>

<li>

<a href='/About/References'>KUNDER</a></li>

<li>

<a href='/About'>OM OSS</a></li>

<li>

<a href='/About/Contact'>KONTAKT</a></li>

</ul></div>

                    <div id="logindisplay" class="span-2">

                            <a href="/Account/LogOn">Logga in</a>



                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

And here's the css for header and headercontent:

```
#headerContent
{
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#header
{

    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000;    
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;

}
```

The overflow and zoom part is just another trick I read about to avoid having to use empty divs to clear containing divs, and I tried without them with no luck, so they have nothing to do with the problem.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width the the `#headerContent` because without it defaults to `width:100%` if you place a `950px` width to the div, you should be fine.

Comment: Actually, that's not the problem, the span-24 class gives it a 950px width. I mentioned that it had that, but forgot to mention where it comes from. This is part of the Blueprint framework. I found the solution however, I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: you shouldn't use span-24 on the headerContent apparently in the Blueprint framework, but rather the container class. Here's what worked:

```
        <div id="header" class="blueheader">
            <div id="headerContent" class="container">
                <div id="logo" class="span-6">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
                        <img src="/images/expertinfo.png" width="230" height="62" />
                        </a>
                </div>
                <div id="menucontainer" class="span-14">@Html.Raw(Html.Menu())</div>
                <div id="logindisplay" class="span-2">
                    @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I cannot say I understand exactly why it didn't work before, and that worries me, because I am trying this framework to simplify layout, but this made it harder to understand. As far as I could see it should have worked with the first code too...